# Is it fair for a website to share interview questions publicly?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, hiring

I recently came across this website and found out that an excruciating amount of interviews were shared in great details with what questions were asked, any follow-up questions, answers to these interview questions, and possibly a rough description of the interviewer. These shared interviews concern a lot of the big names in the U.S. tech industry. Clearly, this sabotages the opportunities of other candidates without these privileged information of interviews taken place recently. I'm sure, you've all seen people sharing tiny bit of detail on their interviews on other job search website. But I can assure you the amount of interview detail shared is tremendous.

My question here is whether it's fair for this website to host such information? And will tech companies still find their hiring process fair if some candidates come fully prepared with the answers to a question the interviewers just asked 1 or 2 interviews ago. Because interviewers normally don't change their questions that often, those candidates actually do have higher chance of answering the question correctly.

And if it is not fair for a website to be doing this, what can we do to take it down so other candidates like me and you can get a fair competition?

Comment: In the US, where freedom of speech is almost a religion. Yes, it would be ok (sort of). In fact, take a look at this site https://www.careercup.com/page Maybe it's not as detailed as the Chinese site you mentioned, but that's probably because giving too many details would give away the identity of the person posting that information. However, for other countries and other jurisdictions, I have no idea how such a site would be considered.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic as we don't answer legal questions here.

Comment: "Sabotaging opportunities of others", yeah, that's pretty rich coming from US industries.

Comment: @DavidK I'll edit the question later to not include the legal part.

Comment: @DavidK I'm not seeking any advice nor do I have anyone to turn to with regard to this question I'm asking. Plus, it's acceptable to ask [Is it okay to reveal interview questions to your friends?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/15485/is-it-okay-to-reveal-interview-questions-to-your-friends) and mine is not?

Comment: It never was. Once again, it should be noted that any mention of legality does not automatically make a question off-topic. Any person with sufficient experience such matters can answer without it being an attempt to provide legal advice. Also voting to reopen.

Comment: People also frequently post details of interview questions on this site. I think we typically omit names to protect the innocent, but if you wanted you could probably fill in the blanks.

Comment: "Is it ok?" seems to me to only have two meanings; "is it legal?" or "is it ethical?".  The former is off-topic, the latter is a matter of opinion.

Comment: When I was at university almost every professor I ever had issued students with copies of previous years' exam papers to study as examples.  I don't see how this is any different to that.

Comment: @JonathonCowley-Thom actually, the former is **not** off-topic. There has been discussion after discussion about this. You **can** ask questions about legality in most cases. Nobody is asking for specific legal advice.

Answer (score 6):

> My question here is whether it's okay for this website to host such
>   information?

It is not illegal. It's not limited to China. And it's also not a new thing. These "dumps" have been going on since the interwebs were invented by Al Gore many years ago.

(Search for "google interview questions" or "facebook interview questions" or "[your favorite well-known company] interview questions". Or look at sites like GlassDoor. Plenty of results in English.)

Even before these sites existed, many agents would debrief the candidates they represented and would use the information learned to assist the next candidate (including the questions that are being asked).

> And will tech companies still find their hiring process fair if some
>   candidates come fully prepared with the answers to a question the
>   interviewers just asked 1 or 2 interviews ago. Because interviewers
>   normally don't change their questions that often, those candidates
>   actually do have higher chance of answering the question correctly.

If tech companies are stupid enough to ask the same technical questions repeatedly for which an enterprising candidate could easily get prepared, then they will presumably "suffer" accordingly. It's not all that hard to come up with many questions for virtually any job.

If they can't distinguish between candidates who have memorized the answers from those who really understand what they are talking about, then perhaps they deserve whatever they will get.

When I interviewed candidates, I never asked questions that were so simple to answer. I always asked questions that demonstrate some thought and some understanding of the process. I never asked "puzzle" questions. And I seldom repeated the same question.

In my experience, hiring tech workers isn't like handing out an SAT test or entrance exam (or at least it shouldn't be).

Comment: Those search results would most likely return the typical trick questions that well-prepared candidates would have already known. However, the website I'm referring to posts technical questions with dates of interview, question description, possible solutions, caveats to note. And I would assume they will be sly enough to not simply memorize the answers and recite them but try to fake a reasonable thought process as if they've never met the question and get to the optimal solution they prepared. So it would be hard for interviewers to weed out cheating candidates.

Comment: Like I said, technical questions are hard to come up with by its nature. So for a period of time, some technical questions will linger long enough for those cheaters to exploit. Also, some screening includes online challenges where candidates take a online coding test, and these online challenges are leaked in the website as well.

Comment: True, I should've looked at the search results before commenting again. Nevertheless, the questions in the other websites are not as up-to-date as this one I'm talking about. But I do find this website [CareerCup](https://www.careercup.com/page?pid=amazon-interview-questions) share the similarity. But at first glance, CareerCup doesn't seem to contain that many leaks of online challenges/assessments.

Comment: @chuck Some web sites have collected questions and labeled them as "leaked" in order to hype them up. It's more reasonable to just treat them as questions that *could* be asked.

Comment: @Brandin As I said, the website takes it to the next level. It's being constantly updated by people currently on the job market. So the questions leaked would have a lot higher chance of re-surface within a few interviews.

Comment: @chuck There are books on the market that collect such questions; those are not illegal. Similar questions are on Stackoverflow.com and this site as well. No reasonable interviewer assumes technical problems they pose will not "leak" out. Besides, if a candidate comes in after having managed to memorize them all, maybe he is a good hire after all?

Comment: @Brandin Let's say, candidate A just came in for an technical interview with company C, and A posted details of the interview on the website, then candidate B happen to come across that thread A posted and B actually is scheduled for an interview with company C today or only several days later with the same interviewer. And the interviewer is very likely to ask B at least a subset of the questions A was asked. Would you still believe it's a fair hiring process for other candidates who doesn't see the thread A posted?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Well, some companies have made their candidates sign NDA. And some companies simply just don't care even if they know these sites are out there and candidates are "well-prepared". It's not a rant when some big companies start to follow suit as the latter. These big companies will give out already-leaked online challenges and after two online challenges candidates are hired without even an in-person interview or phone screening. Shocked? This happens for a while now in a big company.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Sorry, I'm not asking if it's illegal or not. The question was already edited. I'm asking if it's fair. Do companies find if it's fair for their candidates? What else can we do? I can't come up with a proposal because I don't know the answer myself. But I would say if interviewers change their questions every interview, things might change and become relatively fair again.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I mentioned in other comments that algorithmic interview questions are all about your thought process and whether your answer is (sub)optimal enough, that is how you get from assumptions to a brute force solution, and eventually to a optimal solution. If a candidate give you his/her memorized answer off the top of his/her head, then you'd know he's seen this question before. But candidates that are "prepared" enough, would fake the thought process. Also given the nature of algorithmic questions, it's very hard for interviewers to not repeat questions between candidates.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it's unclear where you're from, so we can't possibly know ***exactly*** what the law is in *your* country.

However, ***typically***, there are no laws or rules as to what you can share about the interview unless you've signed a non-disclosure agreement.

Is it *"unfair"* to share these details with others? **I don't think so.**

We each prepare ourselves for an interview as best we can. For myself, I prepare canned answers to a wide range of hypothetical questions, most of which come up in interviews in some shape or form. Should my preparation be illegal? How about studying for an exam?

I think you can see where I'm going with this.

Ultimately there's going to be a lot of different factors which tie into a company offering you a job. Not just what you say, but *how* you say. How you come across in a million little ways.

And last but not least, ***life is not fair***, friend. There's no such thing as a fair competition. We each try to gain an advantage over one another, whether it's some unique experience we list on our resume's, or a tidbit of knowledge you glean off of someone's LinkedIn profile and use to form a personal connection (with a witty, off-handed comment, *of course*).

Instead of focusing on what the other guy is reading online, worry about your own efforts to prepare.

Comment: The "How about studying for an exam?" metaphor breaks down somewhat when what we're talking about here is sharing the exam questions before the exam... Personally I'd be appalled if I discovered a candidate had performed such _preparations_.

Comment: @RJFalconer - there's standard HR questions which everyone asks. ***"Tell me about a time you've been wrong."***. Or ***"What's your biggest strength/weakeness?"***. These seem to fall out of fashion every once in a while, but the questions which replace them all essentially ask the same thing. Anyone with a good head on their shoulders will google **"Typical Interview Questions"** and prepare answers to those "top 10 questions you _have_ to know". It's simply common sense. Similarly, when preparing for an exam you know the topics which you'll be tested on. Doesn't mean you'll pass.

Comment: Here I'm specifically referring to algorithmic questions typically asked in tech companies.

Comment: @chuck - those also change, and furthermore, they are not the deciding factor in a hiring decision. If you're asked to explain your solution and you don't know how because you simply regurgitated the answer, then you won't do any better than a guy who stumbles around looking for an answer and fails, but in the process demonstrates the capacity to think logically and critically. There's websites out there listing little "trick" programming questions to ask in interviews. I once "caught" an interviewer using such a question. He wasn't amused when I joked that "we checked out the same site".

Comment: "Well-prepared" candidates would be sly enough to not simply memorize the answers and recite them but try to fake a reasonable thought process as if they've never met the question and get to the optimal solution they've always prepared.

Comment: @RJFalconer It's more like sharing past exam papers, which most universities do, so the "study for an exam" metaphor is sound.

Comment: ""Well-prepared" candidates would ...to the optimal solution they've always prepared. "

A lot of people would call what you've described "learning how to do something new".  Is looking at Stack Overflow and Dream In Code "cheating" as well?

Comment: @JonathonCowley-Thom Well, past exam papers have higher standard deviation though a long period of time, whereas questions asked by the same interviewer several interviews apart won't vary that much. It's more like a recitation hosted by TAs (who creates final tests) specifically to prepare for the exam and questions that are very likely to appear in the finals. However, due to the nature of these interviews being shallow and superficial, this "recitation"-kind-of leak gives away too much information for one to be able to successfully fool an interviewer or an online judge of online tests.